# Force call to paintComponent

Tags: java, user-interface, awt

I realise this code looks, pointless, I've just got rid of the irrelevent stuff to show the structure

```
class Drawer extends JComponent {
  public Drawer(int[] data) {

    System.out.println("drawer");

    for(int x = 0; x < data.length; x++){}
      //work out what to draw
    repaint();
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);     
    System.out.println("drawerpC"); //check to see if it is called
    //draw stuff
  }  
}
```

In a separate file, a new instance of `Drawer` is called regularly. Every time it is called, `data` is different, and so every time `Drawer` is called, `paintComponent` needs to be called.

I have this code in that other file:

```
Drawer d = new Drawer(data);
myGUI.con.add(d); //myGUI.con is a previously set up container
```

`repaint()` is not causing `paintComponent` to be called (otherwise you'd see the stdout), so how can I force `paintComponent` to be called for every calling to `Drawer`?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson I can't really make it compliable and short at the same time, so I went for short.

Comment: It only takes a handful more lines to make that an SSCCE.  'Short' can easily be 100 lines of code without most people complaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the `int[]` as a class attribute.  Move `//work out what to draw` into `paintComponent(Graphics)`.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `repaint` will have no effect until the component is part of the display hierarchy. It can't possibly be part of a hierarchy while the constructor is still executing.

One option is to add a [`HierarchyListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/HierarchyListener.html) to the root of your display hierarchy and do the repaint there. However, it's far from clear to me what you're trying to accomplish and this might not be the best approach.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say ho it is implemented. I've edted the question.

Comment: @ACarter - Well, my point about calling `repaint` (sorry about calling it `redraw`) in the constructor still holds. Why not just call `d.repaint()` (or `myGUI.con.repaint()`) right after calling `myGUI.con.add(d)`?

Comment: Just tried `d.repaint()`, `myGUI.con.repaint()`, and `myGUI.repaint`, and none of them worked :(